# Automatic transmission shift problem on a 2002 Chevrolet Impala

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, automatic-transmission, shifting, impala

I recently bought this car with an automatic  transmission. After I backed up, I could not get it to go into drive. I reset the car by turning it off and then on until it worked. Last few times I've driven it, it has not happened. Had the transmission fluid checked and it was good. No noise or other issues.

What could be the cause of the car not shifting back into Drive?

Are there some things I can check to make sure the basics are covered?

Why would a transmission shift into reverse and not shift into drive?

Comment: Will the shifter not move into drive or will the car not move forward with the shifter into drive?

Comment: Car won't move forward

Comment: Shifts just fine, acts like it did not go into drive and continues to go in reverse

Answer (score 4):

Look at your shift linkage cable, it may be loose or parts that it attaches to may be worn out.

- Remove the trim around your shifter to look at that end of the cable, make sure it's firmly attached and not wobbly.
- Get under the car and find the other end of it on your transmission housing. Make sure it's secure and not wobbly. Block the wheels and get somebody else to move your shifter while you are looking at it.

[This guy](https://youtu.be/JP-o0i3jkkc) is showing you how to change the bushing, but it also shows you what the shifter arm looks like on your vehicle.